# why the input tag prints user input in the 'value' atttribute

Tags: php, html

I have the following code from somewhere and I don't know the reason why there is a need to have the 'value' attribute in the input tag. I deleted it and the code worked perfectly. Is is for security reasons ? or am I missing something ?

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" maxlength = "30" value= "<?php if (isset($_POST['username'])) echo $_POST['username']; ?>" required>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: the value attribute with what you're using now is required in order to be able to pass it on to another method somewhere and to possibly echo it back in there

Comment: *"Is is for security reasons ?"* - not really, if you want to secure it, look up XSS exploits/injection

Comment: This is normally used so that when you are reporting an error in the input, the user does not have to re-type all the inputs that were not in error. Basically it is setting the value shown in that field to what had been entered by the user before the form was submitted

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks so much, This answered my question